# R: How to add missing dates to a dataframe twofold and and give each a different value in other column?

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have the following dataframe which is actually part of a much larger one:

```
[7080,] 20100303 3.669138e-01  0.000000000
[7081,] 20100303 4.347603e-01  0.000000000
[7082,] 20100305 4.252109e-01  0.000000000
[7083,] 20100306 3.865164e-01  0.000000000
[7084,] 20100307 2.799683e-01  0.000000000
[7085,] 20100307 3.478009e-01  0.000000000
[7086,] 20100309 3.381812e-01  0.000000000
```

As you can see the first column consists of dates of which some have 2 measurements and others have 1. However some dates are missing.

If a date is missing I want to create two different "measurements" for that particular date, one with value "0" and one with value "1" in the second column (I want value "1" to be above "0"). The value of the third column has to be 99 (not NA). The result would be something like this:

```
[7080,] 20100303 3.669138e-01  0.000000000
[7081,] 20100303 4.347603e-01  0.000000000
        20100304 1             99
        20100304 0             99
[7082,] 20100305 4.252109e-01  0.000000000
[7083,] 20100306 3.865164e-01  0.000000000
[7084,] 20100307 2.799683e-01  0.000000000
[7085,] 20100307 3.478009e-01  0.000000000
        20100308 1             99
        20100308 0             99
[7086,] 20100309 3.381812e-01  0.000000000
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Help would be awesome!

Comment: Please give us a reproducible example. A small subset of your data that can be easily copied to our own workspace.

Comment: Copy and paste and use this function?: df<-read.table(text="")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't give us variable names so I made some up:

```
# alldates       # a vector of all possible dates
# currentdates   # your current dataframe variable of dates
```

To get all `alldates`, you might try generating the range of all possible dates from the origin of your timeseries up to some point in the future. For example the following gives the first 10 days starting after 1900-01-01:

```
as.Date(1:10,origin = "1900-01-01")
```

With that in hand, it should be relatively easy to do what you're requesting:

```
# generate a vector of all missing dates
z1 <- rep(alldates[!alldates %in% currentdates],each=2) 
# generate a vector of 0's and 1's
z2 <- rep(c(1,0),(length(z1)/2)) 
# generate a vector of 99's
z3 <- rep(99,length(z2)) 
cbind(z1,z2,z3) # put it all together
```

You can then add this to your original data using `rbind` or whatever.